# Autohotkey not working correctly on .jpg files

Tags: html, autohotkey

I have been using a hotkey to record data on different images. Currently I'm trying to record the number of species seen in each image. The hotkey opens on right click, I select a number button, and the hotkey closes. It used to be that the number (and any image data) would then be recorded in a text file. This will still happen if I run the hotkey on a txt file but not on a .jpg file. Instead of being added to the .txt file, the .jpg file is copied to the clipboard. I recently updated my computer so I'm guessing that something was changed somewhere. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I've retried old codes and unrelated pictures that had worked in the past but I get the same problem now.

Below is an example of my code. My goal is to open a .jpg image, right click to open the hotkey, select a number (in this example, 1, 2, or 3) and the window should close. The information from the image (date/time and image name) should appear with the selected number (1, 2, or 3) in a .txt file.

```
;Set time correction (in hours) for daylight savings/time zone changes.
Timecorrection = 0
;Set text IDs for buttons. This same text will be recorded in the data file.

button1 = 1
button2 = 2
button3 = 3

RButton::
ifwinnotexist, Image Index Script
{

Gui, destroy
Gui, Show , w625 h410, Image Index Script
Gui, Add, Button, x10 y192 w90 h40 vBUTTON1 gB1,%button1%
Gui, Add, Button, x110 y192 w90 h40 vBUTTON2 gB2,%button2%
Gui, Add, Button, x210 y192 w90 h40 vBUTTON3 gB3,%button3%
Gui, Add, Button, x110 y12 w90 h40 vBUTTON26 gTEST,Test
Gui, Add, Button, x210 y12 w90 h40 vBUTTON27 gRESET,Reset
Gui, Add, Button, x310 y12 w90 h40 vBUTTON28 gOpenData,View Data
Gui, Add, Button, x410 y12 w90 h40 vBUTTON29 gHighlight,Highlight
Gui, Add, Button, x10 y12 w90 h40 vBUTTON30 gCANCEL,Cancel
Gui, Add, Button, x510 y312 w90 h40 vBUTTON31 gEdit,Edit Code
Gui, Add, Button, x510 y352 w90 h40 vBUTTON32 gExit,Exit App

return
gettime:
{
send,^z
sleep, 40
;Extract modification date from file. Note: this extracts the date on which the file was last modified, which will be the time
;when the image was taken unless it has been cropped or otherwise modified, in which case that date will be extracted instead.
FileGetTime, CreationDate, %clipboard%, M
CreationDate += %Timecorrection%, Hours
FormatTime, CreationDateFormatted, %CreationDate%, M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss 
SplitPath, clipboard, name
Sleep, 10
FileAppend, %Name% %CreationDateFormatted% %count%`n, 
%A_ScriptDir%/Data.txt
sleep, 100
return
}
clip:
{
Gui, Submit, Hide
gui, destroy
sleep, 40
clipboard =  ; Start off empty to allow ClipWait to detect when the text has arrived.
Send ^c
ClipWait
return
}
Repeat:
{
gosub,clip
gosub,gettime
sleep,20
return
}
OpenData:
{
Run, %A_ScriptDir%/Data.txt
return
}
B1:
{
Dest = %button1%
gosub,clip
gosub,gettime
sleep,20
return
}
B2:
{
Dest = %button2%
gosub,clip
gosub,gettime
sleep,20
return
}
B3:
{
Dest = %button3%
gosub,clip
gosub,gettime
sleep,20
return
}
TEST:
{
Dest = Test
gosub,clip
gosub,gettime
sleep,40
sleep,20
return
}
Highlight:
{
Dest = Highlights
gosub,clip
sleep,40
sleep,20
return
}
RESET:
{
Gui, Submit, Hide
gui, destroy
Reload
return
}
Edit:
{
Edit
return
}
Exit:
{
Exitapp
return
}
CANCEL:
{
Gui, Submit, Hide
gui, destroy
sleep, 40
return
}
end::
{
gosub, Repeat
MsgBox, 4,,%Dest%,0.5
send,{right}
return
}
return
}
else
{
Gui, Submit, Hide
gui, destroy
sleep, 40
return
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code so that we can try to help you? It's difficult to give any suggestions or assistance without knowing the code that is being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I recently updated my computer so I'm guessing that something was changed somewhere"

If you updated from Windows 10 to Windows 11, they are very different beasts and many scripts cease to continue working correctly afterwards. Posting your failing script and stating the system you are running on may yield some results.

Comment: Thanks. I am working with a Windows 10 system. the updates I am referring to are auto updates. I'm not sure what was updated but it's the only thing I can point to that changed.